# Django Static_Root CDN setup for production

Tags: django, cdn

I am using Cropperjs and Opencv for users to crop an image, this requires the temporary upload of a file to the `static_root` or `media_root` folder that is deleted after cropping. I am using Amazon S3 for production static files but I am unsure how to setup the `static_root` to use Amazon S3 in production? I am using Heroku for production if that matters?

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "src.cdn.backends.MediaRootS3Boto3Storage" #backends.py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static", # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles-cdn" # CDN for production?
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles-cdn" / "uploads"

TEMP = MEDIA_ROOT / "temp"
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets):

> Django won’t automatically create the target directory (STATIC_ROOT)
> that collectstatic uses, if it isn’t available. You may need to create
> this directory in your codebase, so it will be available when
> collectstatic is run. Git does not support empty file directories, so
> you will have to create a file inside that directory as well.

So static_root layout like the following works to save an image temporarily before uploading to AWS S3:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'uploads')

TEMP = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'temp')
```